# Codewars Grasshopper - Personalized Message c

Tags: c

I've started using Codewars to learn C and this problem is giving me issues. When I attempt to submit the answer I get errors against their test cases. I'm not sure what I did wrong or left out but any advice would be appreciated.

Errors:

*"The expression (as strings) (greet(danielToo, "Daniel")) == ("Hello boss") is false: actual=`Hello guest` expected=`Hello boss`."*

*"The expression strcmp(greet(second, secondCopy), greetChecker(second, second)) == 0 is false."*

Instructions:

*"Create a function that gives a personalized greeting. This function takes two parameters: name and owner."
Use conditionals to return the proper message:*

*name equals owner  'Hello boss'*

*otherwise  'Hello guest'*

My code:

```
const char* greet(const char *name, const char *owner) {
  if (name == owner)
    {
      return "Hello boss";
    }
    else
    {
      return "Hello guest";
    }
  return "";
}
```

Test cases:

```
#include <criterion/criterion.h>

const char* greet(const char *name, const char *owner);

Test(ExampleTests, ShouldPassAllTheTestsProvided) {
    cr_assert_str_eq(greet("Daniel", "Daniel"), "Hello boss");
    cr_assert_str_eq(greet("Greg", "Daniel"), "Hello guest");
    static const char danielToo[] = "Daniel";
    cr_assert_str_eq(greet(danielToo, "Daniel"), "Hello boss");
    cr_assert_str_eq(greet("Cat", "Catherine"), "Hello guest", "Cat is not Catherine");
    cr_assert_str_eq(greet("Catherine", "Cat"), "Hello guest", "Caterine is not Cat");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your checking if the two values point to the same place in memory, you should change your if condition to strcmp(name,owner) == 0. This function will return 0 if the two passed arguments are equal.
You can learn more about it here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm

Answer (score 0):

The comparison `name == owner` checks whether the pointers are the same, which is not a necessary condition for the strings to be equal.

See also, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/8004250/13134095.

Comment: Thanks for the help, still new to C and haven't gotten a handle on the different ways to use it.